# MEF Factory Pattern with a parametrized Constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, mef, factory, lazy-initialization

I am trying to implement the factory pattern using MEF.
what i am doing is having Interface of the product class and make the concrete classes be exported with Metadata that is different in each of the concrete classes.
in the Factory class i have a list of Lazy loaded Interface of Products along with their corresponding metadata, as follow:

```
 [ImportMany("Product")]
 public List<Lazy<IProduct, IProductMetaData>> ProductTypes;
```

then in the create function i filter that aforementioned list of product types to return the one implementation given as  parameter to the create function:

```
public IProduct CreateProduct(string type)
       {
           var productType = ProductTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Metadata.Type == type);
           return productType .Value;   
       }
```

till this point every thing works fine. but what if each of the concrete Product classes to be returned by the factory class have a parameter in its constructor.???

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `Product` classes have an `ImportingConstructor` decorating the said constructor, MEF will take care of satisfying these imports when the class is actually instantiated (when you access the lazy object's `Value` property), so you have nothing to worry about.